# Wordpress website replaced by Symfony : old URL still in log

Tags: wordpress, symfony

Before I had a WordPress landing page on my domain : [www.becowo.com](https://www.becowo.com)

1st of April, I replaced this landing page with my new Symfony website, on the existing domain.

Since, I can see errors in logs when trying to acccess old WP admin URL (for sure because they don't exists anymore). But who/what can try to access these urls ?

How can I clean this ?

Here is an extract of the logs :

```
[2017-04-18 04:03:57] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /wp-login.php"" at /xxxxx/var/cache/prod/classes.php line 2773 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /wp-login.php\" at /xxxxx/var/cache/prod/classes.php:2773, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /xxxxx/var/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:888)"} []
[2017-04-18 04:03:58] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /wp-admin" (from "https://www.becowo.com/wp-login.php")" at /xxxxx/var/cache/prod/classes.php line 2773 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /wp-admin\" (from \"https://www.becowo.com/wp-login.php\") at /xxxxx/var/cache/prod/classes.php:2773, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at xxxxx/var/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:888)"} []
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Search engine bots, vulnerability scanners, etc... Will try to access your old `wp-admin` url because they probably have seen it in the past.

You can setup a `301` to your home by simply adding a rule to your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```